# I need to show side menu in wordpress

Tags: plugins, menus

I am quite new to wordpress, And quite confused about wordpress.

I am building a website to write programming topics. When user is suppose opened  **"Java Inheritance** in the left sidebar must show the list of all the topics covered in Java.

For example, [I took inspiration from this site](https://www.javatpoint.com/super-keyword). How to show the topics list in left sidebar.

I want to make php file, which can be installed in wordpress folder inside server. And how can I proceed to write the **PHP** and what to write in the **PHP** file which should show topics of Java in sidebar.

Correct my errors.Thanks

Comment: Start by reading https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sidebars/

Comment: Thnk for reply: Are you sure this would serve my purpose? How much time required? And Is there any important point to take care of for development.

Comment: If your new to WordPress and plan to develop with it then you need to learn how to use it.

Comment: You may want to start out by installing a few different themes and see if one fits your needs for now, i.e. showing Categories in a sidebar, or letting you add Widgets to a sidebar, which are both quite common. From there you can start reading documentation if you want to actually affect the code and not just write content.